# Conserver botón de UI al presionar backbutton

Tags: android, back-button

En mi app tengo 2 botones (iniciar y finalizar), pero solo se muestra uno a la vez, si hago clic en "iniciar" se borra y aparece el botón "finalizar". Mi problema es que cuando hecho clic en "iniciar" y luego presiono el backbutton y vuelvo a entrar a la app debería salirme el botón de "finalizar" pero me sale el de "iniciar" nuevamente. Alguien me podría decir cómo puedo mantener el botón que haya quedado antes de salir de la app?

Comment: ¿Podrías poner el código que tienes actualmente y la relación que tienes dentro del storyboard?

Comment: No se entiende muy bien la duda que planteas, podrías añadir algo de código para poder ver ejemplos y tenerlo más claro?

Comment: Mi app inicia con un botón que tiene el texto "INICIAR" que al presionarlo se oculta y muestra otro de texto "FINALIZAR", y este al ser presionado se oculta y vuelve a mostrar el botón "INICIAR". Mi problema es que si salgo de la app (button back) estando el botón "FINALIZAR" mostrado y vuelvo a entrar a la app, debería seguir el mismo, pero aparece el botón de "INICIAR"

Comment: El problema que tienes es que una vez cierras la app, pierdes todo control sobre ella, es por eso que al volverla a iniciar se carga automáticamente el botón Iniciar de nuevo, ya que es lo que se muestra al arranque. Deberías ayudarte con algún indicador externo para saber si se tiene que mostrar el botón iniciar o finalizar, ya sea por BD, archivos de texto, etc, y de esta manera al hacer el LOAD de la aplicación comprobar qué botón debe mostrar.

Answer (score 0):

Al cerrar la aplicacion se pierden los datos que hayas hecho sobre ella, para lo cual debes controlar esto con un indicador externo ya sea por DB, archivo o lo que sea, no hay otra opcion en caso de que la aplicacion se cierre.

Otra opcion  que no se si te convencera, pero aun asi te doy la idea, es que programes que a la hora de cerrar no se cierre la aplicacion sino que se quede en segundo plano, de esa forma mantendria los datos guardados para cuando volviese a abrirse y te quitas el lio de guardar datos.

Espero haberte sido de ayuda